# Build QT Mysql driver for Mac OS Catalina

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I have been working my way diligently through all the QT Tutorials I can find, and so far very impressed with what can be achieved. However I now need to start with databases, and starting out with MYSQL.

I have no come across the famous:
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7

I am working on a MAC with OS 10.15.4 Catalina
QT5.14.2 (Open Source Licence)
MYSQL 8.0.19

I have installed Connector/C++ 8.0.19 as per the instructions provided at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html

Following the same set of instructions I execute the following in the terminal window:

*cd /Users/Edward/Qt/5.14.2/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers
qmake -- MYSQL_PREFIX=/usr/local
make sub-mysql*

The first line of the above is modified to suit my installation location, the remainder is as per the example provided on the website.
However when I execute:
*qmake -- MYSQL_PREFIX=/usr/local*

I get the following response:

Usage: qmake [mode] [options] [files]

QMake has two modes, one mode for generating project files based on
some heuristics, and the other for generating makefiles. Normally you
shouldn't need to specify a mode, as makefile generation is the default
mode for qmake, but you may use this to test qmake on an existing project...
followed be all the options available.
If I then execite the final line of:
make sub-mysql

I get the following response:

make: *** No rule to make target `sub-mysql'. Stop.

I have searched high and low for a solution to this problem, however none of the posting I found have helped me to resolve this problem.

Additional information.
I used the QT online installer.
I uninstalled and downloaded source and tried to compile from source, there were so many errors in this process I decided to uninstall and do a clean install using the online installer again.

My installation folders for all key elements are as follows:

```
/Users/Edward/Qt/5.14.2/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers
/usr/local/mysql-8.0.19-macos10.15-x86_64
/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.19
```

I am on a steep learning curve, and doing my best to work my way through the forums and anywhere else I can find potential solution, but after three day of beating my head against the wall I would greatly appreciate if anyone can give me some guidance in layman terms so I an understand what I am doing wrong and fix the problem.

My thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: The qmake call works for me. Is the qmake in your path from Qt 5.14.2?

Comment: QMake works, as it turns out I was executing the command from the incorrect folder. I found a great post on the QT forum which laid out step by step how to solve this problem:https://forum.qt.io/topic/106565/mysql-qt-create-plugin-mysql-for-qt-on-mac. Once I corrected the folder I was in, I was just missing the last step of changing the environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who experiences this problem the following post fixed it for me:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/106565/mysql-qt-create-plugin-mysql-for-qt-on-mac.

the user lays out step by step how to create and install the plugin as well as adjusting the environment variable.

Comment: This. Note that I had to follow the pretty hidden instruction in the comments, to delete the file `config.cache`, before the qmake call registered my MySQL installation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short torurial:

1. install mysql via homebrew: `$ brew install mysql`
2. install Qt Source (I install Qt into default path -- my $HOME directory `/Users/liuhao`) https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstarted.html
3. open Terminal and change path to `/Users/liuhao/Qt/5.15.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers`
4. run `/Users/liuhao/Qt/5.15.2/clang_64/bin/qmake  -- MYSQL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql` (watch out for the spaces around `--`)
   and you will get some messages like:

```
$ /Users/liuhao/Qt/5.15.2/clang_64/bin/qmake  -- MYSQL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql

Running configuration tests...
Done running configuration tests.

Configure summary:

Qt Sql Drivers:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. yes
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... no
  PostgreSQL ............................. no
  SQLite2 ................................ no
  SQLite ................................. yes
    Using system provided SQLite ......... no
  TDS (Sybase) ........................... no

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'make install'.
Qt will be installed into '/Users/liuhao/Qt/5.15.2/clang_64'.

Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from
the previous build.
```

5. `$ make sub-mysql` and then you can find new mysql driver dylib files in `/Users/liuhao/Qt/5.15.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/plugins/sqldrivers`

```
$ ls -alh /Users/liuhao/Qt/5.15.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/plugins/sqldrivers
total 3360
drwxr-xr-x  6 liuhao a   192B Aug 20 18:29 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 liuhao a    96B Aug 20 16:17 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 liuhao a   1.5M Aug 20 18:24 libqsqlite.dylib
drwxr-xr-x  3 liuhao a    96B Aug 20 18:23 libqsqlite.dylib.dSYM
-rwxr-xr-x  1 liuhao a    94K Aug 20 18:29 libqsqlmysql.dylib
drwxr-xr-x  3 liuhao a    96B Aug 20 16:17 libqsqlmysql.dylib.dSYM
```

6. copy it to `/Users/liuhao/Qt/5.15.2/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers/` and you will be able to use it in qt project.

```cpp
foreach (QString driver, QSqlDatabase::drivers ())
{
    qDebug() << driver;
}
/*
available drivers
...
"QMARIADB"
"QMYSQL"
"QMYSQL3"
...
*/
```